# Import androidsettings.setting file with ADB

Tags: android, adb

I have an "xxx.setting" XML file exported from an interactive whiteboard running Android.
I want to distribute this file to the multiple other interactive whiteboards remotely through ADB and then execute the file with the package `com.seewo.easifinder.`

The package has the following activities

```
Activity Resolver Table:
  Full MIME Types:
      application/xapk:
        1c350b9 com.seewo.easifinder/.xapk.XApkInstallerActivity filter 670b80
          Action: "android.intent.action.VIEW"
          Category: "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
          Scheme: "file"
          Type: "application/xapk"
      */*:
        ad7ecfe com.seewo.easifinder/.FileRetrieverActivity filter 623e214
          Action: "android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT"
          Category: "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
          Category: "android.intent.category.OPENABLE"
          Type: "*"
          mPriority=0, mOrder=0, mHasPartialTypes=true
        ad7ecfe com.seewo.easifinder/.FileRetrieverActivity filter ba18abd
          Action: "android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT"
          Category: "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
          Category: "android.intent.category.OPENABLE"
          Type: "*"
          mPriority=0, mOrder=0, mHasPartialTypes=true
        ad7ecfe com.seewo.easifinder/.FileRetrieverActivity filter 73bd8b2
          Action: "android.intent.action.PICK"
          Category: "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
          Category: "android.intent.category.OPENABLE"
          Type: "*"
          mPriority=0, mOrder=0, mHasPartialTypes=true

  Base MIME Types:
      application:
        1c350b9 com.seewo.easifinder/.xapk.XApkInstallerActivity filter 670b80
          Action: "android.intent.action.VIEW"
          Category: "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
          Scheme: "file"
          Type: "application/xapk"

  Wild MIME Types:
      *:
        ad7ecfe com.seewo.easifinder/.FileRetrieverActivity filter 623e214
          Action: "android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT"
          Category: "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
          Category: "android.intent.category.OPENABLE"
          Type: "*"
          mPriority=0, mOrder=0, mHasPartialTypes=true
        ad7ecfe com.seewo.easifinder/.FileRetrieverActivity filter ba18abd
          Action: "android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT"
          Category: "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
          Category: "android.intent.category.OPENABLE"
          Type: "*"
          mPriority=0, mOrder=0, mHasPartialTypes=true
        ad7ecfe com.seewo.easifinder/.FileRetrieverActivity filter 73bd8b2
          Action: "android.intent.action.PICK"
          Category: "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
          Category: "android.intent.category.OPENABLE"
          Type: "*"
          mPriority=0, mOrder=0, mHasPartialTypes=true

  Schemes:
      file:
        1c350b9 com.seewo.easifinder/.xapk.XApkInstallerActivity filter 670b80
          Action: "android.intent.action.VIEW"
          Category: "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
          Scheme: "file"
          Type: "application/xapk"

  Non-Data Actions:
      android.intent.action.MAIN:
        2997c5f com.seewo.easifinder/.FileBrowseMainActivity filter 19c3467
          Action: "android.intent.action.MAIN"
          Category: "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
```

I have uploaded the settings file to `/sdcard/mnt/Documents`

If I manually tap on the settings file on the device then I'm prompted to accept that current settings will be overwritten.
I have tried to use the application manager. With no luck :) I'm new to ADB and Android so I'm probably just missing something obvious.

```
am start -n com.seewo.easifinder/.FileRetrieverActivity -d "content:/sdcard/mnt/Documents/xxxxx.setting"
```

The result is that the com.seewo.easifinder open file dialog box is launched on screen. But the file specified is not executed.
I hope you can point me in the right direction so I can get com.seewo.easifinder to execute the settings file.

OS: Android 9
Device: Clevertouch Impact Plus 2

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I cant see how i can limit it further than i already did my question is  How do I execute the xxx.setting file through ADB on the devices?.

Comment: Ah i see what you mean Robert. Thank you for your input. I have updated the post to try to clarify what I need help with. I hope I succeeded :)

Comment: Based on what you have posted and already tried it seems that there is no activity that would allow settings import. As the app is not public I assume it belongs to the whiteboard, so you should contact the whiteboard manufacturer and ask how to import the settings file via adb.